# Как переставить элементы массива задом-наперед? C++

Tags: c++, массивы

дан массив и нужно его элементы просто развернуть.
например, дан массив `arr[]=1, 2, 3;`
а нужно развернуть так `arr[]=3, 2, 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы решение Ildar переписал так:

```
void reverse(std::vector<int>& arr) {
    for(size_t i = 0, j = arr.size() - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        std::swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }


void reverse(int arr[], int size) {
    for(size_t i = 0, j = size - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        std::swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
```

Принцип тот же, но мне кажется, так понятнее.

Answer (score 5):

```
reverse(arr,arr+size(arr));
```

См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Answer (score 2):

возможная реализация без использования итераторов, чтобы алгоритм не был для вас чёрным ящиком

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


void reverse(std::vector<int>& arr)
{
  const size_t size = arr.size();
  for (size_t i = 0, half = size / 2; i < half; ++i) {
    std::swap(arr[i], arr[size - i - 1]);
  }
}


int main()
{
  std::vector<int> arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
  reverse(arr);
  std::cout << arr[0] << arr[1] << arr[2]; // 321

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: По мне логично после "чтобы алгоритм не был для вас чёрным ящиком ", подумать, что в таком случаи и  std::vector вполне может оказаться черным ящиком

Comment: @ARHovsepyan так то да, так далеко можно копать :)))